# Pandas-Merge Multiple Column Values to a NumPy Array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to extract the Word Embeddings for a text dataset. Since Elmo takes a lot of time for a huge dataset, I tried to parallelize the process by dividing it into batches and store the values in a CSV File. Now I have a data frame that consists of around 1024 Columns which contains the word embeddings.

Example Dataframe:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.25 | 0.4 |
| 0.2 | 0.3 | -0.1 |

What I need to do is to combine the values row-wise to a column and this needs to be a Numpy Array rather than a list.
This is what I need it to look like:
PS: The values in Col 4 need to be of type NumPy array.

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.25 | 0.4 | [0.1,0.25,0.4] |
| 0.2 | 0.3 | -0.1 | [0.2,0.3,-0.1] |

What I've tried so far:

> > np.array(DF.iloc[:,0:1023].values.tolist())

But this throws the following error:

> > ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1023, placement implies 1

How do I do this? Any advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try `apply` on axis 1 with `to_numpy`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col 1': {0: 0.1, 1: 0.2},
                   'Col 2': {0: 0.25, 1: 0.3},
                   'Col 3': {0: 0.4, 1: -0.1}})

df['Col 4'] = df.apply(lambda s: s.to_numpy(), axis=1)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   Col 1  Col 2  Col 3             Col 4
0    0.1   0.25    0.4  [0.1, 0.25, 0.4]
1    0.2   0.30   -0.1  [0.2, 0.3, -0.1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close, need `.tolist()` after converting to numpy array:

```
df['Col 4'] = np.array(df.to_numpy()).tolist()
print (df)
   Col 1  Col 2  Col 3             Col 4
0    0.1   0.25    0.4  [0.1, 0.25, 0.4]
1    0.2   0.30   -0.1  [0.2, 0.3, -0.1]
```

For your data:

```
DF['Col 4'] = np.array(DF.iloc[:,0:1023].to_numpy().tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

You can use `apply()` method and `array()` method:

```
df['Col4']=np.array(df.apply(np.array,1))
```

Output of `df`:

```
   Col 1  Col 2  Col 3             Col 4
0    0.1   0.25    0.4  [0.1, 0.25, 0.4]
1    0.2   0.30   -0.1  [0.2, 0.3, -0.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.array` within `.apply()`, as follows:

```
df['Col 4'] = df.apply(np.array, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   Col 1  Col 2  Col 3             Col 4
0    0.1   0.25    0.4  [0.1, 0.25, 0.4]
1    0.2   0.30   -0.1  [0.2, 0.3, -0.1]


df['Col 4'].map(type)

0    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
1    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Name: Col 4, dtype: object
```

Comment: btw it is exact same like https://stackoverflow.com/a/67518811/14289892 but you just removed upper covering...ie `np.array()`

Comment: Same result, but simplified way of doing the same thing.   No need to use 2 `np.array()`.  Just one is enough.  This is the subtle difference that we need to notice.

Comment: even If you just remove `np.array()` but It is exact same solution....bruh..btw I agree that it is more simplified there is no need

Comment: I think we got to avoid redundant codes.  Of course you can say 1 * (2 + 3) is the same as (2 + 3) but which one would you use ?